# Analizador Roslyn para archivos .config

Tags: c#

Consulta, será posible crear un analizador Roslyn que aplique solamente para los archivos .config?. Necesito crear un analizador que verifique ciertas variables declaradas en los archivos config de una solución, pero no encuentro información sobre como configurar el alcance de estos.

De momento tengo esto, pero me busca todas las variables en todos los archivos, menos en los config.

```
            var root = syntaxTree.GetRoot();
            var comments = root.DescendantTrivia().Where(trivia => trivia.IsKind(SyntaxKind.SingleLineCommentTrivia)).ToList();



            foreach (var comment in comments)
            {
                string commentText = comment.ToString();
                if (commentText.Contains("NombreVariable"))
                {
                    var diagnostic = Diagnostic.Create(Rule, comment.GetLocation(), "NombreVariable");
                    context.ReportDiagnostic(diagnostic);
                }
            }
```

Comment: 3 cosas: 1. Bienvenido a SOes. 2. Lectura recomendada: https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que veas el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso obtengas tu primera medalla. 3. ¿Es necesario usar Roslyn? Porque lo que estás haciendo es leer un XML (según entiendo) y buscar si existe alguna variable, ¿cierto?

Comment: Hola, si es necesario el uso de Roslyn, ya que estoy implementando varias reglas dentro de SonarQube.